# Change Android CheckBox icon check/unchecked

Tags: android, checkbox, icons

I am new at Android. I am trying to change the icon of the CheckBox.

Here is my code, where star_checked and start_unchecked are .png file in my drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="=@drawable/star_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

I am getting the following error: 
C:...\app\src\main\res\drawable\selector_priority.xml:3: AAPT: error: '=@drawable/star_checked' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr) reference.

Any idea of what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the equals sign "=" before `@drawable/star_checked`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, i can't believe I missed this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to syntax error you are using an extra equal sign in `android:drawable="=@drawable/star_checked"` this line.

Use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_checked" />
<item android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_unchecked" />
</selector>
```